# Symfony 4.0.4 cannot install mailgun bundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, mailgun

Installing mailgun bundle for Symfony breaks down "`bin/console`" command

How and where to get working mailgun bundle for Symfony 4?

```
$ composer require cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle:*
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 11 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing php-http/discovery (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/message-factory (v1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing clue/stream-filter (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/message (1.6.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/promise (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/httplug (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/client-common (1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing php-http/multipart-stream-builder (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing mailgun/mailgun-php (2.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle (0.1.2): Downloading (100%)         
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Symfony operations: 2 recipes (9b46b734d14be831804cdcde063bdadf)
  -  WARNING  mailgun/mailgun-php (>=2.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:master
    The recipe for this package comes from the "contrib" repository, which is open to community contributions.
    Review the recipe at https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/mailgun/mailgun-php/2.3

    Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): y
  - Configuring mailgun/mailgun-php (>=2.3): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:master
  - Configuring cspoo/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle (>=0.1.2): From auto-generated recipe
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In ArrayNode.php line 238:
!!                                                                
!!    The child node "key" at path "mailgun" must be configured.  
!!                                                                
!!  
!!  

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Kind of looks like the recipe did not give you a working config file.  The should be a config/packages/mailgun.yaml file for you to edit.

Comment: I did a fresh install and got no config file at all.  Looks like you will have to add it yourself and maybe open an issue.

Comment: Looks like the official bundle has not caught up with Symfony 4 at all yet, there are some compatibility pull requests not merged

Comment: Perhaps.  I don't use it myself.  But it does seem very strange to make the effort to publish an incomplete recipe.  Even if it was intended for 3.4.